# Selenium Tests not running on jenkins with firefox 50

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

```
###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x2E007D,name=PBrowser::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot send/recv

JavaScript error: resource://app/modules/ContentCrashHandlers.jsm, line 75: TypeError: browser.permanentKey is not a non-null object

###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x2E007D,name=PBrowser::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot send/recv

org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFORMATION: Detected dialect: W3C

###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x2E007D,name=PBrowser::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot send/recv
```

When I run my tests with selenium 3.0.1 with firefox 50 I get the following error, with other browsers they work fine. Also if I start the tests from eclipse with firefox they also work normally but an exception shows at the end of the test run.

**UPDATE for people with the simlar issue**

I have tried this with different versions of Firefox and here is what I found:

- The only one that works is Firefox 48.
- Firefox 47 is explicitly not supported as mentioned [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver)
- Firefox 49 and 50 have problems until now. You can see [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues) people reporting different issues they have with them.

  **UPDATE 2:**

There is a new gecko driver that was released this month 0.13.0. I tested it with Firefox 50 and it works.

**UPDATE 3:**
Firefox 53 works with geckodriver 0.16 and selenium 3.4

Comment: `browser.permanentKey` is null but cannot be

Comment: how can i fix this?

Comment: I've found that the last stable version for MY test suite is the 46.0.1. Have you considered downgrading Firefox?

Comment: @Sim1  48 is working fine as well